# Fully expanded \str_if_eq test

Tags: expl3, expansion

I am sure I am getting something utterly wrong, but I am also sure this used to work with previous versions of `latex3`:

```tex
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myifstreq}{ m m m m }
    {
        \str_if_eq:eeTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
    }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    
    \begin{document}
        
        \myifstreq{Müller}{Müller}{equal}{not equal}
        
        \myifstreq{M\"uller}{Müller}{equal}{not equal}
        
    \end{document}
```

[image]

How do I make this test fully expand the two arguments before comparison?

Comment: But the strings are not equal ...

Comment: OK, but then can I set a test that checks whether the expansion of these two strings is equal?

Comment: The problem is you are actually wanting to compare the result of typesetting the input, rather than the input itself: as David says, the nearest you'll get is purifying the input (to remove markup), which is not exactly meant for this task but will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are checking the expansions, and they are not equal

consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\expanded{\def\noexpand\qqq{{M\"uller}{Müller}}}\show\qqq
\end{document}
```

which shows the expansions.

With pdflatex (OT1) you get

```
> \qqq=macro:
->{M\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {u\
global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\let \begingroup \let \ty
peout \protect \begingroup \def \MessageBreak {
(Font)              }\let \protect \immediate\write \m@ne {LaTeX Font Info:    
 on input line 5.}\endgroup \endgroup \relax \let \ignorespaces \relax \accent 
127 u\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor ller}{Müller}.
l.5 ...noexpand\qqq{{M\"uller}{Müller}}}\show\qqq
                                                  
?
```

with lualatex (TU) you get

```
> \qqq=macro:
->{Müller}{Müller}.
l.5 ...f\noexpand\qqq{{M\"uller}{Müller}}}\show\qqq
                                                  
?
```

and as you see, in pdflatex the two words do not expand to the same thing.

You could use `\text_purify:n` to remove the accent tex markup

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
 \ExplSyntaxOn
\expanded{\def\noexpand\qqq{{\text_purify:n{M\"uller}}{\text_purify:n{Müller}}}}\show\qqq
 \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

produces

```
> \qqq=macro:
->{Müller}{Müller}.
l.5 ...uller}}{\text_purify:n{Müller}}}}\show\qqq
                                                  
?
```

with pdflatex and lualatex

---

Prior to 2022 latex releases, inputenc non-ascii characters were not robust in the same way and would break in an expansion-only context. So actually you would get a "true" test but the two equal "strings" were "accidental broken nonsense" in each case. The first form above, in 2020, gave

```
> \qqq=macro:
->{M\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {u\
global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\let \begingroup \endgrou
p \relax \let \ignorespaces \relax \accent 127 u\egroup \spacefactor \accent@sp
acefactor ller}{M\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempb
oxa \hbox {u\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\let \beging
roup \endgroup \relax \let \ignorespaces \relax \accent 127 u\egroup \spacefact
or \accent@spacefactor ller}.
l.5 ...noexpand\qqq{{M\"uller}{Müller}}}\show\qqq
                                                  
?
```

where the two forms do both have the same expansion, but probably not the intended string to test.

Comment: Thanks, David, this makes sense. Using `\text_purify:n` works indeed. I still wonder why the test used to work until recently. Has this been a l3 bug? Also, is it possible that `\text_purify:n` is rather slow? (I am using this test in the `biblatex-publist` package to check whether we have the `\plauthor` which can be input in different way, and this seems to be much slower on a reasonably sized publication list)

Comment: Ah, actually it would have worked by accident in older latex Give me a second, I will update the answer about that.

Comment: @JSpitzm I added a note about older releases

Comment: Excellent, good to know.